# How was this data conversion performed exactly?

Tags: python, binary, type-conversion, bit-manipulation, unpack

So, long story short, I am trying to 'unpack' some data myself, but I am not able to do so. Fortunately I have the solution, but I cannot figure out the method. Basically, I have this array of data here,

> [16  130  164   65  103  136  209   64   19   36  185  190   83]

, and I am told that when 'unpacked' via `'fffB'`, I get:

> [ 20.56350708,   6.54790068,  -0.36160335,  83]

I know for a fact that this solution is correct, but I am not sure how we attained it.

The context here is that the input array was 'unpacked', using Python's command as so:

```
struct.unpack_from('fffB', input)
```

However try as I may, I am unable to understand the exact operation here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to convert the list of numbers to a string since that's what [`unpack`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) expects:

> Unpack from the buffer buffer (presumably packed by pack(fmt, ...)) according to the format string fmt. The result is a tuple even if it contains exactly one item. The buffer’s size in bytes must match the size required by the format, as reflected by calcsize().

Number in the list can be converted to characters with [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#chr) and once you `join` them together you have input that can be given to `unpack`:

```
import struct

d = [16, 130, 164, 65, 103, 136, 209, 64, 19, 36, 185, 190, 83]
s = ''.join(chr(x) for x in d) # s = bytearray(d) on Python 3

struct.unpack('fffB', s) # (20.563507080078125, 6.547900676727295, -0.36160334944725037, 83)
```

Format string `fffB` tells `unpack` to extract three floats of 4 bytes each and one unsigned character size of 1 byte. In total 13 bytes are extracted which matches the length of your data. The exact specification of format characters can be found from [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/struct.html#format-characters).

Note that above example only works with Python 2.x, on Python 3.x you need to convert the list to [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#bytearray) instead of string.

Comment: Thanks niemmi, however what is confusing me, is how exactly this conversion is occuring. What I am trying to do is do this conversion 'by hand', and how to do that is what I am being stumped on. I get that the first 4 numbers [16, 130, 164, 65] SOMEHOW give me 20.563507080078125, but how exactly is this occuring? Thanks!

Comment: @TheGrapeBeyond: What Python version are you using? As I mentioned in the answer Python 2 & 3 work bit differently in this regard.

Comment: @TheGrapeBeyond: You can find the explanation for floating point format from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format). You could also try [online converter](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html), if you input `0x41a48210` (first 4 bytes in reversed order) there you get the first number `20.563...`.

Comment: Thakns - I am using Python 2.7.6. I will take a look at online converter. How did you go from [16, 130, 164, 65] to 0x41a48210 however? Cheers.

Comment: I read the online calculator, but I am still befuddled - I am not understanding where and how, the exact numbers 16, 130, 164, 65, enter into the conversion. I am not sure how to start with those numbers such that I can get 20.563507080078125...

Comment: OK, figured it out, flip the whole thing you meant: So: flipping [16, 130, 164, 65] gives [65, 164, 130, 16], and then in this flipped vector, if each number is converted into a 1 byte (8 bit) sequence, we get 01000001101001001000001000010000. Then once we have this binary sequence, we convert it into float, using IEEE-754 conversion. Thanks!