# Is this bit conversion process vectorizable? (MATLAB)

Tags: performance, matlab, type-conversion, bit-manipulation, vectorization

I am trying to speed up a bit conversion process, that is currently in a MATLAB loop and takes a very long time to execute. Here is the problem:

Consider an `input` integer matrix of size `12xN`, where `N` can easily be `100,000`, or so. Then I perform the following operations:

```
output = zeros(3, N);
temp = zeros(3,1);

% Loop through each column
for pp = 1 : N            

     % For each column, convert the first 4 numbers into a float, the second 4 numbers into a float, and finally the third 4 numbers into a float as so:
     for dd = 1:3 
        snip = input(dd * 4 : -1 : (dd-1) * 4 + 1, pp);
        temp(dd) = typecast(uint32(bin2dec(num2str(reshape(dec2bin(snip,8).',1, 32))) ), 'single');        
     end

     % Now simply store the result
     output(1:3,pp) = temp;
end
```

I am basically converting each column into 3 floating point numbers, but I would like to see if there is any way in which I can speed up this process, and remove the loop(s) you see here.

Is there such a way? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Here is an example to illustrate my goal: Suppose our `inputMatrix` is a `12 x 4`, composed of:

```
   65   65   66   65
  164  168  175  174
  130  232    2  222
   16  138   86   27
   64   64   66   65
  209  240   59   12
  136  185  207  101
  103   33   18  172
  190  190   64  190
  185  182  121  184
   36   41  153  173
   19   55  127  183
```

The output after my conversions, (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37095796/how-was-this-data-conversion-performed-exactly/37095959?noredirect=1#comment61735585_37095959) for conversion/unpacking to floating point via IEEE-754 standard), will be an `output` of values:

```
    20.5635   21.1135   87.5046   21.8584
    6.5479    7.5226   46.9522    8.7748
   -0.3616   -0.3558    3.9000   -0.3607
```

Thus, the first 12-element column of `inputMatrix` will give the first 3-element column of `output`. (In other words, [16, 164, 30, 16] will give 20.5635, and [16, 64, 209, 136] will give 6.5479, etc).

What I would like to do, it vectorize this operation on this matrix as much as possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typecast` is vectorized, so you can just feed the entire input array to it. (Note that `input` is the name of a built-in function, so you should really name your variable something else.) The result is a column vector, so you need to reshape it afterwards.

I had to flip the byte order in the input array, so I just did `flipud` on the entire array. This put the resulting floats in the wrong order, so I just repeated `flipud` on the result.

```
>> A = [   65   65   66   65
          164  168  175  174
          130  232    2  222
           16  138   86   27
           64   64   66   65
          209  240   59   12
          136  185  207  101
          103   33   18  172
          190  190   64  190
          185  182  121  184
           36   41  153  173
           19   55  127  183];    

>> Af=flipud(uint8(A));

>> B = flipud(reshape(typecast(Af(:), 'single'), 3, []))
B =

   20.56351   21.11354   87.50456   21.85845
    6.54790    7.52260   46.95222    8.77482
   -0.36160   -0.35578    3.89999   -0.36070
```

Update: My previous version (which runs on Octave) just typecast the full matrix `A`. MATLAB is apparently pickier and wants a vector, so the update converts the matrix into a column vector using `A(:)`. Everything else is the same.

Comment: Hi beaker, for some reason the typecast I have complains that 'the first argument must be a vector'...

Comment: We're getting the same behavior on MATLAB (I had tested on Octave). I'll update the answer.

Comment: Hi beaker, ok so the (:) operator took care of that, but I do not think that the answer (of the actual conversion) is the same between my code and your code. I think that the subtlety in my code is what allows me to take one input column, and give out 3 floats. This conversion is not happening in your code... thanks.

Comment: If you can give some sample input and output (maybe 1 or 2 columns) perhaps I can see what the difference is.

Comment: I think we're running into a byte ordering problem. We should be able to get around this easily, but I'd like to get some sample data from you so I can verify rather than just guess. :)

Comment: Sure, let me put an example up. :-) PS it's exactly related to this problem I had earlier, (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37095796/how-was-this-data-conversion-performed-exactly/37095959?noredirect=1#comment61735585_37095959), but I will put an example up nonetheless.

Comment: I edited the question with a thorough example. Let me know if that helped. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @beaker, this was extremely helpful!